# findIndex Array method in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm very new to Angular 4 development. I encounter `someArray.findIndex()` is not a function. How to add this `.findIndex()` javascript function in TypeScript.

I'm building a calendar component, following function gives me error

> **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_lodash**.findIndex is not a function
>       at CalendarComponent.isSelected (calendar.component.ts:4

```
isSelected(date: moment.Moment): boolean {
    return _.findIndex(this.selectedDates, (selectedDate) => {
      return moment(date).isSame(selectedDate.mDate, 'day');
    }) > -1;
  }
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not about Typescript. Javascript functions are included in Typescript. You are trying to use [Lodash](https://lodash.com) function. Make sure that you installed and imported it on top of the file:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

or just use Javascript function:

```
isSelected(date: moment.Moment): boolean {
    return this.selectedDates.findIndex((selectedDate) => {
      return moment(date).isSame(selectedDate.mDate, 'day');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This solved my problem. I've missed to install the `lodash` module.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `findIndex` method of _. You are either using `UnderscoreJS` or `Lodash`.

As the error says **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_lodash.findIndex is not a function** It means you are using lodash.

Import lodash library and it will work.

> `import _ from 'lodash';`

Answer (score 1):

```
selectedDate = arrayName.find(item => item.date === searchingdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use indexOf

```
[1,2,3,4,5].indexOf(1) //return 0
[1,2,3,4,5].indexOf(5) //return 4
[1,2,3,4,5].indexOf(6) //return -1
[1,2,3,4,5].indexOf(0) //return -1
```